# C++ - Finding nearest neighbor using opencv flann

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I have two set of points (cv::Point2f): setA and setB. For each point in setA, I want to find its nearest neighbor in setB. So, I have tried two methods:

1. Linear search: for each point in setA, just simply scan through all points in setB to find nearest one.
2. Using opencv kd-tree:

   _ First I built a kd-tree for setB using opencv flann:

   ```
   cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams indexParams;
   cv::flann::Index kdTree(cv::Mat(setB).reshape(1), indexParams);
   ```

   _ Then, for each point in setA I do query to find nearest neighbor:

   ```
   kdTree.knnSearch(point_in_setA, indices, dists, maxPoints);
   ```

Note: I set maxPoints to 1, cause I only need the nearest one.

I do a bit study, and come out with some time complexity for each case:

1. Linear search: O(M*N)
2. Kd-Tree: NlogN + MlogN => first term for building kd-tree, second term is for querying

Where M is number of points in setA, and N is for setB. And range of N: 100~1000, range of M: 10000~100000.

So, the kd-tree is supposed to run much faster than the linear search method. However, when I run the real test on my laptop, the result is kd-tree method is slower than linear search (0.02~0.03s vs 0.4~0.5s).

When I do profiling, I got hot spot at knnSearch() function, it takes 20.3% CPU time compares to 7.9% of linear search.

Uhm, I read some online articles, they said to query kd-tree it usually take logN. But I am not sure about how opencv implement it.

Anyone knows what's wrong here? Is there any parameter I should adjust in kd-tree or did I make mistake somewhere in the code or computation?

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the [Flann documentation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf). For low dimensional data, you should use **KDTreeSingleIndexParams**.

```
KDTreeSingleIndexParams
```

When passing an object of this type the index will contain a single kd-tree optimized for searching lower dimensionality data (for example 3D point clouds), in your case 2D points. You can play with the leaf_max_size parameters and profile your results.

```
struct KDTreeSingleIndexParams : public IndexParams
{
    KDTreeSingleIndexParams( int leaf_max_size = 10 );
};

max leaf size: The maximum number of points to have in a leaf for not
branching the tree any more
```

Comment: Wow, that's nice! I haven't seen this in the documentation, thanks for pointing it out. I will try it, and update to you soon.

Answer (score 1):

O(log(N)) doesn't necessarily mean it is faster than O(N).
This is only true for sufficiently big N.
Your N is a rather small number. If your kd-tree contained millions of elements, you'd probably see the difference between a linear scan and a logarithmic search.

So my guess is that you spend a lot of time with overhead like building the tree, which is slower for small N than just scanning this rather small list without any overhead.

Comment: Yup, your opinion is reasonable, and I have thought about that too. That's why I have done the profiling, and it shows that that bottle neck is from kd-tree querying, not from building kd-tree. That makes me confused! Thanks for your point also.

Comment: You're right, I just made a test. Building the tree isn't the problem. But let's say you have 100 entries in the kd-tree. Now assume, that knnSearch() just takes a little longer for one query than the linear search on 100 entries, because it's a bit more complex. This will add up linearly with your amount of queries. Now if you have 100000 entries in the kd-tree, the linear search is probably slower for 1 query and thus for many queries. In order to profit from the kd-tree's logarithmic search you have to store many data in it.

Comment: Uhm, that's what i thought too. Now, I m trying another method, I split the image into small grids, and do local search within the grid that the point belongs to. If there is no point in the grid, I will search in neighbor grids.

Comment: @OhMyGosh you can either generally go by binary space partitioning (like KD-Trees or Quad-Trees) or you could use spatial hashing. All of them have different advantages and disadvantages, depending on your use-case.